# How to convert a bitmap to a jpeg file in Android?

Tags: android, file, bitmap, jpeg

I have a cropped bitmap image and I need to save it into a jpeg file.

How do I convert it from a bitmap to a jpeg file in Android?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14723418/4294399

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outStream);
```

Here is a sample Program

[compressing-a-bitmap-to-jpg-format-android](http://android.okhelp.cz/compressing-a-bitmap-to-jpg-format-android-example/)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Good point. To those who don't know how to use this approach: 1. `ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();` 2. `bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);` 3. write byte[] into file or use it anywhere else (for example you can show it in ImageView with the help of Glide lib)