# Convert bitmap to jpeg android

Tags: android

I have a bitmap captured from taking photo in android. The photo is in Bitmap. I have to convert this bitmap into JPEG without any loss. I tried the below code,

```
val file = File(filePath)
profileImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,FileOutputStream(file))
```

but when I set the jpeg image using RoundedBitmapFactoryDrawable, the captured image is very small. I want to the exact bitmap to jpeg. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that might be useful:

> Use this:
>
> ```
> Bitmap bmp = null;
> ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.jpeg, 100, stream);
> byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
> ```
>
> for that you can use this:
>
> ```
>     FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;
>
>     File file = new File("yourfile");
>
>     byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
>
>     try {
>         //convert file into array of bytes
>   fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
>   fileInputStream.read(bFile);
>   fileInputStream.close();
>
>   //convert array of bytes into file
>   FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
>               new FileOutputStream("C:\\testing2.txt"); 
>   fileOuputStream.write(bFile);
>   fileOuputStream.close();
>
>   System.out.println("Done");
>     }catch(Exception e){
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```
>
> and also for more info go with [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Please read [How to convert a bitmap to a jpeg file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329090/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-a-jpeg-file-in-android) for more solutions

Hope it help