# How to send bitmap via http post to server

Tags: android, image, http

I have a picture from camera as bitmap.
This picture I want to send as jpeg to the server via http Post, something like this:

```
Bitmap photo;
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(photo);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

I have this code from azure

```
//Request headers. 
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey); 
// Request body. 
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{\"url\":\"upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/comm‌​ons/c/c3/…\"}"); 
request.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

Comment: convert your pic to base_64 string and send it

Comment: How do I convert it to base64?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920967/android-post-base64-string-to-php

Comment: I encoded it now as byte and tried to add a Byteentity. but seems not to work

Comment: check out the second link in previous comment

Comment: I have this code from azure // Request headers.
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request body.
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/RH_Louise_Lillian_Gish.jpg\"}");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

Comment: That would be JSON, not an image

Answer (score 1):

Convert your bitmap to base64 string, try below code and post that string to server

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
   Bitmap immagex=image;
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
   byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
   String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
   return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
   byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
   return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all convert bitmap to jpeg.
For converting bitmap to jpeg, you can refer to : -
[How to convert a bitmap to a jpeg file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329090/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-to-a-jpeg-file-in-android)

After that use multipart entity to send files to server.

To send files to server: -

```
InputStream is = null;
String response ="";
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
mpEntity.addPart("profile_pic", new FileBody(new File(profileImagePath)));

try {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    response = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
```